# activeClassName not applying to Link when path is descendant to parent

Tags: reactjs

This is my route configuration:

```
<Link className="nav-link " activeClassName="active" to={'/parent'}>
   parent
</Link>
```

When I visit the url: https://localhost:8000/some-url/#/parent/ react applies the class `active` to link. But when I visit the path: https://localhost:8000/some-url/#/parent/child , react doesn't apply the `active` class.

Any suggestion on how to get the active class to be applied on the link when url is any descendent of the parent.

I have followed the [documentation](https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html) which says

> The  will be active if the current route is either the linked
>   route or any descendant of the linked route. To have the link be active only on the exact linked route, use  instead or set the onlyActiveOnIndex prop.

But not sure why it is not getting applied by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insted of using `Link` you should use `NavLink` as the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) says

> A special version of the `<Link>` that will add styling attributes to
>   the rendered element when it matches the current URL.

by using `NavLink` you should be able to achieve this also you can use things like `exact`,  `strict`, `isActive`